# Issues with JMenuBar Flyout in a Java swing app

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

im having issues with my JMenuBar. I have added a image  with the code below. I would like the exit under the file menu - image no. 1 (like a drop down ) and the insert under the edit tab - image no.2. For some reason the witch should also be under the edit tab isn't displaying - image no.3. When you hover over search in the edit menu I would like image no.4,5 and 6 to appear. I think all of these points are related. Can anyone see my mistake? hope the picture helps make my question more clear, Thanks in advanced!

[image: menu issues]

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.text.*;

 public class DVD1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
//construct components
JLabel sortPromt= new JLabel("Sort by:");
JComboBox fieldCombo= new JComboBox();
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

//initalize data in arrays
String title[]={"Casablanca", "Citizen Kane", "Singin in the rain", "The wizzard of Oz"};
String studio[]={"Wanner Brothers", "RKO Pictures", "MGM", "MGM"};
String year[]={"1942", "1941", "1952", "1939"};

 //construct an instance of DVD
 public DVD1()
 {
    super("Classic on DVD");
 }
 //create the menu system
 public JMenuBar createMenuBar()
 {
    ///create instance of menu bar
    JMenuBar mnuBar =new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(mnuBar);

    //Construct and Populate the File menu
    JMenu mnuFile = new JMenu("File",true);
        mnuFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        mnuFile.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
        mnuBar.add(mnuFile);

    JMenuItem mnuFileExit =new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mnuFileExit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        mnuFileExit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(1);
        mnuBar.add(mnuFileExit);
        mnuFileExit.setActionCommand("Exit");
        mnuFileExit.addActionListener(this);

    //construct and pop the edit menu
    JMenu mnuEdit = new JMenu("Edit",true);
        mnuEdit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        mnuEdit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
        mnuBar.add(mnuEdit);

    JMenuItem mnuEditInsert = new JMenuItem("Insert New DVD");
        mnuEditInsert.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_I);
        mnuEditInsert.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(1);
        mnuBar.add(mnuEditInsert);
        mnuEditInsert.setActionCommand("Insert");
        mnuEditInsert.addActionListener(this);

    JMenu mnuEditSearch = new JMenu("Search",true);
        mnuEditSearch.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        mnuEditSearch.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        mnuEditSearch.add(mnuEditSearch);

    JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByTitle =new JMenuItem("By Title");
        mnuEditSearchByTitle.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        mnuEditSearchByTitle.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        mnuBar.add(mnuEditSearchByTitle);
        mnuEditSearchByTitle.setActionCommand("title");
        mnuEditSearchByTitle.addActionListener(this);

    JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByStudio =new JMenuItem("By Studio");
        mnuEditSearchByStudio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        mnuEditSearchByStudio.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        mnuBar.add(mnuEditSearchByStudio);
        mnuEditSearchByStudio.setActionCommand("title");
        mnuEditSearchByStudio.addActionListener(this);

    JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByYear =new JMenuItem("By Year");
        mnuEditSearchByYear.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
        mnuEditSearchByYear.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        mnuBar.add(mnuEditSearchByYear);
        mnuEditSearchByYear.setActionCommand("title");
        mnuEditSearchByYear.addActionListener(this);

    return mnuBar;
}//End menu contructor

//Create the conetnt pane
public Container createContentPane()
{
    //populate the jcomboBox
    fieldCombo.addItem("Title");
    fieldCombo.addItem("Studio");
    fieldCombo.addItem("Year");
    fieldCombo.addActionListener(this);
    fieldCombo.setToolTipText("Click the drop-down arow to display sort fields");

    //construct and populate the north panel
    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        northPanel.add(sortPromt);
        northPanel.add(fieldCombo);

    //Create the JTextPane  and center Panel
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        setTabsAndStyles(textPane);
        textPane = addTextToTextPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
            scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

    //create container and set attributes
    Container c =  getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        c.add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return c;

}//end create container method

//method to create thtab stops and set fontstyles
protected void setTabsAndStyles(JTextPane textPane)
{
    //create Tab Stops
    TabStop[] tabs = new TabStop[2];
        tabs[0] = new TabStop(200, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT,TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
        tabs[1] = new TabStop(350, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT,TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
    TabSet tabset = new TabSet(tabs);

    //set tab style
    StyleContext tabStyle = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset=
        tabStyle.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.TabSet,tabset);
    textPane.setParagraphAttributes(aset, false);

    //set Font Style
    Style fontStyle =
        StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);

    Style regular = textPane.addStyle("regular", fontStyle);
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(fontStyle, "sansSerif");

    Style s = textPane .addStyle("italic",regular);
    StyleConstants.setItalic(s,true);

    s = textPane .addStyle("blod",regular);
    StyleConstants.setBold(s,true);

    s = textPane .addStyle("lard",regular);
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(s,16);

}

//method to ad text to textpane
public JTextPane addTextToTextPane()
{
    Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
    try
    {
        //clear previous text
        doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());

        //Insert title
        doc.insertString(0,"Title\tStudio\tYear\n",textPane.getStyle("large"));

        //insert detail
        for(int j=0;j<title.length;j++)
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),title[j] + "\t",textPane.getStyle("bold"));
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),studio[j] + "\t",textPane.getStyle("italic"));
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),year[j] + "\n",textPane.getStyle("regular"));
        }//end loop
    } //end try
    catch (BadLocationException ble)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldnlt Insert Text");
    }//end catch
    return textPane;
}///end addtexttotextpane method

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  String arg = e.getActionCommand();

  //user clicks the sort by combo box
  if(e.getSource() == fieldCombo)
    {
        switch(fieldCombo.getSelectedIndex())
        {
            case 0:
                sort(title);
                break;
            case 1:
                sort(studio);
                break;
            case 2:
                sort(year);
                break;
        }//end swictch
    } //end if

   //user clicks exit on file menu
    if (arg=="Exit")
        System.exit(0);
   //user clicks insert new dvd on edit menu
    if (arg=="insert")
    {
       String newTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the moive's title");
       String newStudio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the studio for" + newTitle);
       String newYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the year for " + newTitle);

        //Enlarge arrays
        title = enlargeArray(title);
        studio = enlargeArray(studio);
        year = enlargeArray(year);

        //add to arrys
        title[title.length-1] = newTitle;
        studio[studio.length-1] = newStudio;
        year[year.length-1] = newYear;

        //call to sort method
        sort(title);
        fieldCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);

    }//end if

    //user clicks title on search submeu
    if(arg=="title")
        search(arg,title);

    //user clicks title on studio submeu
    if(arg=="studio")
        search(arg,studio);

    //user clicks title on year submeu
    if(arg=="year")
        search(arg,year);

}//end of actionPerfomed method

//Method  to enlarge an arry by 1
public String[] enlargeArray(String[]currentArray)
{
    String[]newArray=new String [currentArray.length +1];
    for(int i = 0; i<currentArray.length;i++)
        newArray[i]=currentArray[i];
    return newArray;
}//end enlarg arry method

//method to sort arrays
public void sort(String tempArray[])
{
    //loop to control number of passes
    for(int pass = 1;pass<tempArray.length;pass++)
    {
        for(int element =0 ; element<tempArray.length -1 ;element++)
            if (tempArray[element].compareTo(tempArray[element+1])>0)
            {
                swap(title,element,element+1);
                swap(studio,element, element+1);
                swap(studio,element, element+1);

            }//end if
    }//end of loop
    addTextToTextPane();
}//end of sort method

//method to swap two elements of an array
public void swap(String swapArray[], int first, int second)
{
    String hold;//temp area to hold for swap
    hold = swapArray[first];
    swapArray[first] = swapArray[second];
    swapArray[second] = hold;

} //end swap method

public void search (String searchField, String searchArray[])
{
    try
    {
        Document doc = textPane.getDocument();//assing text to document object
        doc.remove(0,doc.getLength());//clear previous text

        //display colomTitles
        doc.insertString(0,"TITLE\tSTUDIO\tYEAR\n",textPane.getStyle("large"));

        //Prompt users for search data
        String search=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the " + searchField);
        boolean found= false;

        //search arrays
        for (int i=0; i<title.length; i++)
        {
            if(search.compareTo(searchArray[i])==0)
            {
             doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),title[i] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("bold"));
             doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),studio[i] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("italic"));
             doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),year[i] + "\n", textPane.getStyle("regular"));
            }//end if
        }//end for
        if (found = false)
        {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your search produced no results.", "no results found", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         sort(title);
        }//end if
    }//end try
    catch(BadLocationException ble)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't insert text.");
    }//end catch
}//End serach method
//main method executes at runtime
public static void main(String args[])
{
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    DVD1 f =new DVD1();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setJMenuBar(f.createMenuBar());
    f.setContentPane(f.createContentPane());
    f.setSize(600,375);
    f.setVisible(true);
}//end main method



 }//end dvd class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you are trying to insert your menu items directly to the MenuBar, and not to its Menu. You shall use:

```
JMenu.add(JMenuItem menuItem)
```

instead of

```
JMenuBar.add(JMenu menu)
```

Example for your code:

```
mnuFile.add(mnuFileExit);  // instead of mnuBar.add(mnuFileExit);
```

And so on for your other menu items.

Comment: Thanks Perfect i see i just had to do that to all the items.Works well.

Comment: Pleasure. Yes, the same remark applies to all items, i've updated my answer